# Send link in SMS NOT including domain name

Tags: text, sms

I know text messages are text based and i can't include html code. But is there something I can do so iPhone users will have a clickable link without the domain name.

So instead of check out my_domain.com/file.html

I have Chck Out MY FILE

=> my file => clickable links like a

Answer (score 0):

SMS messages are text-only, most apps on iOS or Android recognize domain names or phone numbers written on them and automatically create a link.  However, you can't create a link without a domain name.  This wouldn't make any sense neither -- where is the link target supposed to be?